# Setting Up and API inside ASP.net (URL issues?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Now i realise this question may get voted down a bit because its not really a direct problem. I am very confident in C# and JavaScript ... so i decided to finally learn ASP.net (.net framework). I understand what API's and AJAX calls do such as handling data and starting API function to retrieve data. But how do you connect the two together inside a project?

**This is the WEBAPI.config**

```
 namespace SignalRDbUpdates
 {
   public static class WebApiConfig
   {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
 }
}
```

**Here is the API i have not set anything up on it yet just want to know how to start an AJAX call to this API ... maybe simply return a string to an alert box for now.**

```
namespace DotNetFramework.Controllers.API
{
public class TestAPI : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
}
```

**This is the AJAX call the URL posting is what confuses me, and expansion of AJAX get too would be appreciated**

```
$.ajax({
               method: 'POST',
               url: '?',
               success: function()
               {
                   alert('Working');
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
```

To recap all i want to know how does using an API with AJAX actually work on a basic level of calling and sending data and retrieving and getting data from the API. The URL section of this is what confuses me the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the scaffolded code, particularly the commented items, it should give you what you're looking for.

e.g.

```
 // GET api/<controller>
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
```

That means to hit that endpoint, your url: `/api/teSTaPi` (purposely showing that casing doesn't matter) with a `GET`. Your `Controller` name = `<controller>` in the scaffolded comment (aka "placeholder"), which in this case, is `TestAPI` (your controller class name).

- naming convention `TestController` so you can use `/api/test/`

In Web API, the default names of the methods and params (or none) will map to the protocol (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) and specific method call.

REF: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Hth...

Comment: This is awesome thank you! So just im clear lets say for example my controlelr is called TestApi and a public void called Function i would simply just say /api/TestApi/Function. Thanks again!

Comment: @paddockson Yes, if you your function/method name isn't named after one of the `HTTP` protocols.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @EdSF